# What is the syntax for using the RadGrid between filter

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

What is the syntax for using the RadGrid between filter in the built-in context menu?  I am using a DataTable as my datasource.  When I apply the 'greater than' filter it works, but the between filter isn't working.   I have tried:

```
81000,82000
81000|82000
81000 and 82000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to separate the value with a **[SPACE]**

like: **81000 82000**

Reference: [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation-Basic Filtering](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-basic-filtering.html)

> **Between:** Same as: value1 <= dataField <= value2. Note that value1 and
>   value2 should be separated by **[space]** when entered as filter.